# This works on one account but not another. What could cause this?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

These functions run individually, `createSchdMedEvents` and `createUrgentMedEvents` run when a form is submitted. The third `createEvent` function is set to run when a ui element is clicked. Everything seems to be working fine on my own Google account. But, when I put the code into the duplicate spreadsheet associated with my work account, it doesn't create the events in the Google calendar.

```js
//Function to submit sheet data to Calendar Event

const eventDuration = 3;
const calendarTrans = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("b9nlem0nd055i0003cktlkemlo@group.calendar.google.com");
const calendarMedical = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('7ct5c0angq01hti2i1na6h81c4@group.calendar.google.com');

//Function to create Urgent Care entry to Medical Calendar
function createUrgentMedEvents() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//
  const ss = ws.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    const created2 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    const schdMed = ss.getRange(i,15).getValue();
  
    if (created2 == "Urgent Care"){
      //const schdMed = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
      const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); // Destination
      const rider = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // Ride Date and Departure time
      const apptTime = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); // Appointment Time
      const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); // Return Time (Depart Location to return to WH)
      const hoursMinutes = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes(); // Time of departure for Description Text
      const phone = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Phone Number
      var startingDate = new Date(date) 
      var endingDate = new Date(date)
      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)

      calendarMedical.createEvent('Driver ?, ' + rider + ' ' + eventName + ', Depart WH @'+hoursMinutes, startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: 'Driver:\n \nRider:\n' + rider + ', ' + phone + '\n' + '\nDepart WH@ ' + hoursMinutes + '\nAppointment Time: ' + apptTime + '\nDepart Appointment @ ' + returnTime })

      ss.getRange(i, 15).setValue("Medical Created")
 
    }
  else if(schdMed == "Medical Created")
  {break;}
    

  }
}

//Function for Scheduled Medical Event to Medical Calendar
function createSchdMedEvents() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//
  const ss = ws.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    const created2 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    const schdMed = ss.getRange(i,15).getValue();

    if (created2 == "Scheduled Medical") {
      //const schdMed = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue();
      const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); // Destination
      const rider = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // Ride Date and Departure time
      const apptTime = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //Appointment Time
      const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); //Return Time (Depart Location to return to WH)
      const hoursMinutes = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes(); // Time of departure for Description Text
      const phone = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Phone Number
      var startingDate = new Date(date) 
      var endingDate = new Date(date)
      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)

      
      calendarMedical.createEvent('Driver ?, ' + rider + ' ' + eventName + ', Depart WH @'+hoursMinutes, startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: 'Driver:\n \nRider:\n' + rider + ', ' + phone + '\n' + '\nDepart WH @' + hoursMinutes + '\nAppointment Time: ' + apptTime + '\nDepart Appointment @' + returnTime })

      ss.getRange(i, 15).setValue("Medical Created")

    
    }
  else if (schdMed == "Medical Created")
  {break;}  

  }
}

//Function to create General Transportation Event in Passenger Van Calendar
function createTransportationEvents() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//
  const ss = ws.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    const created1 = ss.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
    const created2 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();

    if (created1 != "Event Created") {
      const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); // Destination
      const rider = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // Ride Date and Departure time
      const apptTime = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //Appointment Time
      const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); //Return Time (Depart Location to return to WH)
      const hoursMinutes = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes(); // Time of departure for Description Text
      const phone = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Phone Number
      var startingDate = new Date(date)
      var endingDate = new Date(date)
      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)

      calendarTrans.createEvent('Driver ?, ' + rider + ' ' + eventName + ', Depart WH @'+hoursMinutes, startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: 'Driver:\n \nRider:\n' + rider + ', ' + phone + '\n' + '\nDepart WH @' + hoursMinutes + '\nAppointment Time: ' + apptTime + '\nDepart Appointment/Lesson: @' + returnTime })

      ss.getRange(i, 14).setValue("Event Created")
    }

  }
}

// Create a Button to schedule events
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("  Submit")
    .addItem("Transportation", "createTransportationEvents")
    .addToUi();
}
```

Additionally, I'm getting `TypeError: date.getHours is not a function createTransportationEvents  @ Submit to multiple Calendars.gs:93` for the `createTransportationEvents` function. It looks the same as the other two functions. I know I'm missing something there. Very new to programming. Thank you for your help. 
 
@TrauzerHamz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it return as a string from:

```
const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
```

if that's a date, turn this into a date object:

```
const date = new Date(ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue());
```

Then you should be able to get hour from this date.

Comment: Thanks @liquidkat, That fixed the date issue. Any idea why the minutes are truncated when a zero is present?

Comment: what's is in the ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue()? Try to log one and see, if you see there only 'mm/dd/yyyy' when this string convert to date object , it has only month, date, year. if the log shows like Fri Feb 18 2022 14:44:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), then it will has all the object come with a date.